# Transparent notificationbar/statusbar for Android 4.3

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 4.3-jelly-bean, java

How can i make the notification/statusbar for Android 4.3 transparent, i know launchers like Dodol Launcher, Smart Launcher and Go Launcher has a transparent bar option. But i want it to be like it is in Android 5.0's notificationbar, so if the bar is light blue the statusbar becomes a little darker blue color.

i don't mean to do it in like Youtube, i mean if you can program it into an Android app, like this `import system.ui.transparentbar`

Comment: Are you rooted?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! This site is for users of Android, which means that questions about development/programming are off-topic here (see the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). Development questions are on-topic on our sister site [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). You might also wish to consult [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) for a fitting place to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - device must be rooted (which of course voids warranty) for having transparent status bar and navigation bar too. And yes, as @Adem said  [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) is the popular way to do that. After that you have to do some workaround for proper functioning of the app. There are some tutorials based on this on [XDA-Dev](http://www.xda-developers.com/) website. Also, there are high chances of soft-bricking the phone in the process.

Comment: I meant like doing it in Eclipse for an app.

Comment: I'm no developer and I don't know anything about that. You could ask this here programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

If your device is rooted you could install [Tinted Statusbar](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.mohammadag.colouredstatusbar) (Xposed). This will do what you want.

Comment: Could you mention a brief description of the said app? That would make this answer more useful to a reader who wouldn't want to click, find and read a description on some other site.

Comment: Be aware that Tinted StatusBar (TSB) requires an enormous amount of configuration; whilst it can automatically detect colours for some apps, you may well need to manually set up colours for each and every app you want it to work with.

Comment: I knew about that app, but i meant more for development, in eclipse. gonna edit my question so it makes sense. but thanks